# Zebra Link OS SDK with Cordova (Phonegap) on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, zebra-printers

I'm trying to generate a plugin for Cordova (Phonegap) for the Zebra SDK (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebralink-multiplatform-sdk.html), to print via bluetooth.

I've created a new Cordova project and refereneced the SDK. On build I recieve these errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MfiBtPrinterConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MfiBtPrinterConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MfiBtPrinterConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CordovaZebraPrint.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there a particular version of the SDK I need to be using or is this something I can fix in my XCode project?

Comment: Ever solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @JamesWagoner - Sorry I forgot about this question. I did I actually sorted the plugin (https://github.com/LiamBateman/cordova-print) it's pretty basic but may help?

Comment: Well I am after printing some barcodes for bin locations in an inventory app I have. I'll check out your plugin and probably hit you up for a question or two.